# Rename hash key but maintain order (without doing an insert new)

Tags: ruby

I want to rename a hash key. This:

```
myhash[preferred_name] = myhash.delete old_name
```

inserts a new key value pair at the last index of my hash. Is there a way to rename a hash without adding a new one?

Comment: When I try your existing solution it appears to work as expected. One key is removed and the value is given a new name. Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: yes it works but it will insert a new hash at the last index which i dont like. I want to maintain the order of the key value pairs in my hash

Comment: I can't find one easily, it might be possible to iterate through and drop all options into a new hash and modify one with a select, but that'll get messy very fast. Just in case it helps, here's the methods available for a Hash https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`transform_keys!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21):

```
h = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }

h.transform_keys! { |k| k == :bar ? :qux : k }
#=> {:foo=>1, :qux=>2, :baz=>3}
```

Just make sure that the new key isn't already present in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

I second @Stefen's answer, with the proviso that it is not necessary to support Ruby versions prior to 2.5, when [Hash#transform_keys!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys-21) made its debut. If earlier versions must be supported, here is one way (that does not create a new hash), an extension of the approach mentioned by the OP.

```
h = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }

h.keys.each { |k| h[k == :bar ? :qux : k] = h.delete(k) }
  #=> [:foo, :bar, :baz] 
h #=> {:foo=>1, :qux=>2, :baz=>3}
```

Note that the enumerators [Hash#each_key](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-each) and [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-each) cannot be used because keys are being deleted during the iteration.

Another choice is the following.

```
keys = h.keys
keys[keys.index(:bar)] = :qux
h.replace(keys.zip(h.values).to_h)
  #=> {:foo=>1, :qux=>2, :baz=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myhash.to_a.each { |a| a[0] = preferred_name if a[0] == old_name }.to_h
```

Or:

```
h.map { |k, v| [k == old_name ? preferred_name : k, v] }.to_h
```

Unfortunately, both solutions will scan the entire structure—even after a match is found—so if your hash has many entries you might prefer one of the other options.